# SQL - Categorize employee entrance time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table where I store every employee IN and OUT timestamp.

There are employees that punch the card more than once (**because they don't hear that the card was read**), other employees that punch the card for some reason (maybe they meet a friend and stay talking for 1 or 2 min) they wait some minutes before they punch again to access the turnstile.

The sample SQL table data looks like this (3 employees only):

[image]

Now, I would like to categorize each time to know what timestamp is correct, etc.

For example:

[image]

In you see **EMP_01** (Yellow record) the LAST_LEAVE technically was 00:38:21 but it's obvious that the employee punch twice that's why the really LAST_LEAVE was 00:38:16.

But, EMP_04 has some other issues, if you see the last 4 records, he has 3 IN's in a row, but those aren't because he didnt hear the beep from the sensor, those are because he leave from other door without punch who knows when, but we know he enter 1 hour after again, and so on.

So, any recommendation on how to deal with this? and how to assign my "Status" flags?

**UPDATE**:

If EMP_04 has 3 consecutives timestamps of the same type (IN's or OUT's) for example:

- 9:04:27am (IN)
- 9:04:35am (IN)
- 9:04:40am (IN)

My tolerance will be 120 seconds between times, so the first time 9:04:27 is OK, but the next 2 consecutive timestamps should be INACTIVE because my tolerance is 120 seconds.

But, for example if EMP_04 has the following consecutive timestamps:

- 9:04:27am (IN)
- 9:04:35am (IN)
- 9:08:10am (IN)

Then the only time marked as INACTIVE will be 9:04:35am. Because between 9:04.35 and 9:08:10am is greater than 2 min.

Comment: What database are you using?  And, can you be a bit more explicit about the rules for the different groups you are looking for?

Comment: SQL 2012, yes I would like to mark as the times that are repeated (maybe with a tolerance of 2 min) as INACTIVE, so If an employe has 3 consecutive IN's then the first IN is not flagged but the next 2 timestamps if the seconds or minutes between them are less than 2 minutes then flagged as INACTIVE.

Comment: I just update the question.

Comment: I still do not get the rule for inactive. The stamp 9:04:35am // will be marked as inactive  because it is within the timeframe (2 minutes) of the previous timestamp 9:04:27am // <-- active?  What status gets the last timestamp 9:08:10am (IN) // IN or Last_In or Last_Leave or Inactive?

Comment: Exactly, lets forget about last_in or out for now I just want to set INACTIVE to times where the gap between them is less than 2min, as you already said.

Comment: +1 for asking in detail with a good format

Comment: How about a trigger that discards duplicate rows that only differ by a timestamp of 120 seconds or less?

Comment: Sounds interesting, any clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, acknowledging @RamRS put the hard work into the trigger, here is one that is tested and should get your started. Clearly some robust testing is needed for corner cases:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TS_FindDups ON dbo.TS FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

;WITH DupRecords
AS
(
        SELECT i.EmployeeId, i.[TimeStamp]
          FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN dbo.TS SRC ON i.EmployeeId = SRC.EmployeeId AND i.EntranceType = SRC.EntranceType
         WHERE SRC.[Status] != 'Inactive'
               /* same day (nice...thanks to RamRS) */
               AND CAST(i.[TimeStamp] AS date) =  CAST(SRC.[TimeStamp] AS date)
               /* only checking newer timestamps (also need this so DATEDIFF <= 2 works correctly) */
               AND i.[TimeStamp] > SRC.[TimeStamp]
               /* newer timestamps are less than two minutes for same Employee, same day, same EntranceType */
               AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, SRC.[TimeStamp], i.[TimeStamp]) <= 2
)

      UPDATE dbo.TS
         SET [Status] = 'Inactive'
        FROM dbo.TS SRC
  INNER JOIN DupRecords ON SRC.EmployeeId = DupRecords.EmployeeId AND SRC.[TimeStamp] = DupRecords.[TimeStamp]

END
```

Comment: A CTE-propelled single statement `UPDATE`. And tested. Consider my mind officially blown!

Answer (score 1):

Like @mdisibio stated, we could use a trigger to add the value "INACTIVE" to duplicate rows while inserting them.

A rough sketch of this trigger would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_FindDups ON tbl_TimeStamp FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentMaxSwipeTime DATETIME
    DECLARE @SwipeType
    SELECT @SwipeType = EntranceType FROM INSERTED

    IF (@SwipeType = 'O')
    BEGIN
        /* Employee is swiping OUT */
        SELECT @CurrentMaxSwipeTime = MAX(T.TimeStamp) FROM tbl_TimeStamp T 
        WHERE T.EmployeeID = (SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED) /* Same employee */
        AND DATE(T.TimeStamp) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) /* Same date */
        AND DATEDIFF(minute,T.TimeStamp,GETDATE())<2 /* Within 2 minutes */
        AND T.Status <> 'INACTIVE' /* of an active swipe */
        AND T.EntraceType = 'O' /* Swiping out */
        AND T.TimeStamp <> (SELECT TimeStamp FROM INSERTED) /* not the row we just inserted, H/T @mdisibio
        IF @CurrentMaxSwipeTime IS NOT NULL
            /* SET Status to INACTIVE */
            UPDATE tbl_TimeStamp SET Status='INACTIVE' WHERE EmployeeID=(SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED) AND TimeStamp=(SELECT TimeStamp FROM INSERTED)
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        /* Employee is swiping in */
        SELECT @CurrentMaxSwipeTime = MIN(T.TimeStamp) FROM tbl_TimeStamp T 
        WHERE T.EmployeeID = (SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED) /* Same employee */
        AND DATE(T.TimeStamp) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) /* Same date */
        AND DATEDIFF(minute,T.TimeStamp,GETDATE())<2 /* Within 2 minutes */
        AND T.Status <> 'INACTIVE' /* of an active swipe */
        AND T.EntraceType = 'I' /* Swiping in */
        AND T.TimeStamp <> (SELECT TimeStamp FROM INSERTED) /* not the row we just inserted, H/T @mdisibio
        IF @CurrentMaxSwipeTime IS NOT NULL
            /* SET Status to INACTIVE */
            UPDATE tbl_TimeStamp SET Status='INACTIVE' WHERE EmployeeID=(SELECT EmployeeID FROM INSERTED) AND TimeStamp=(SELECT TimeStamp FROM INSERTED)
    END
END
```

It's been a few years since I worked on SQL Server, but I really hope there are no errors in the code.

--
Cheers,
Ram

Comment: @VAAA Sorry I missed your interest in the trigger till now. @RAMRS Thank for suggesting this trigger. Two comments: 1) I was thinking more of a `ROLLBACK` if the row is to be ignored. Depends if VAAA really needs to save the rows or if 'Inactive' was a workaround. 2) I need to run a test case to be certain, but I think this trigger will always match to the new inserted records, since they will already exist in the tbl_TimeStamp. I (or anyone else) will work on an alternative.

Comment: Should I maybe add a clause to exclude the current record then?

Comment: Also, I did not suggest a `ROLLBACK` to avoid any data loss.

Comment: Yes, perhaps when selecting @CurrentMaxSwipe time...exclude timestamp values in the inserted table...?

Comment: Good effort. Unfortunately, INSERTED is a table, so some of the join syntax is incorrect...

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the mis-`JOIN`s. And I'll update the `NOT` clause now.

Comment: This trigger does not do a `ROLLBACK` :)

Comment: I think he meant your decision not to use a Rollback was good, and was encouraging you not to follow that particular suggestion from me :)

Comment: Oh! I am against loss of data too, so thank you, @VAAA !

Answer (score 0):

Let me quickly summarise your issues and take them one by one:

1. Duplicate OUT records when swiping twice by mistake. How should the status be set?
2. Duplicate IN records as not all doors have swipe on and don't record the corresponding OUT record. Again How should the status be set?

Assuming:

1. You can get duplicate IN and OUT records if people scan multiple times by mistake.
2. You are not going to get card scanners on the doors that currently don't have them...
3. It's an imperfect system and therefore you aren't going to delete\ignore any scans in different scenarios.

So...
Duplicates Records with a few minutes inbetween. In order to determine the user's status you will have to look at their history. I believe your idea of having a tolerance of a few minutes is a good one although this should be checked on both IN and OUT scans. For IN you should always take the first. For OUT you should always take the last.

What I'm thinking is that every time you insert/update/delete a timestamp record for a particular employee for a particular day you recalculate all their statuses for that day. That way you don't have to worry about shuffling statuses backwards and forwards on different rows if there are duplicate scans.

You will have to recalculate the statuses as below:

1. FIRST_ENTRANCE - First Timestamp row for the employee on a with EntranceType I on a particular day
2. LAST_LEAVE - Last Timestamp row for the employee on a with EntranceType O on a particular
   day for all employees. Check all other employees on this day do not have this on the same day before setting this.
3. FIRST_IN - First Timestamp row for the employee on a with EntranceType I on a particular
   day for all employees. Check all other employees on this day do not have this on the same day before setting this.